# Can no longer log in via GUI to Ubuntu desktop 21.10 after apt purge gnome-shell-common

Tags: login

Trying to fix some other lock screen issue and followed some advice about apt purge gnome-shell-common but this seems to have broken log in via GUI.

Trying to understand how to fix. Have tried to install and reboot.

Comment: sudo apt install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop seems to have gotten around error ... not sure if I've now switched desktop environments though

Comment: If you had standard Ubuntu then reinstalling `ubuntu-desktop` didn't changed that or added another DE.

Answer (score 0):

Log in to the TTY with your username and password and try these commands:

```
sudo apt update 
sudo apt install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
```